# foreign key doubt - mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

one simple question please. I have three tables.

**GROUP**

```
id    area
1   Multimedia
4   Education
```

**Employment**

```
  id   foreign key(GROUP)     job
   1    1                   designer
   2    4                   professor
   3    1                   copy
```

and now suppose that i have this

**SpecificProperties**

```
id  foreign key (Employment)      properties
1   1                             type of contract
2   1                             number of jobs 
3   2                             duration contract (no type of contract)
4   2                             number of jobs
```

the designer and the professor in this case have the property number of jobs. So basically the question is, i need  repeat the number of jobs for each profession? there is any way to avoid? or i can have to number of jobs 8 foreign keys to 8 different jobs for example ? one for designer, other for professor, other for copy, and so on? in this way the first number of jobs have in the foreign key 1 || 2 || 3

something like this:

```
**SpecificProperties**

    id  foreign key (Employment)      properties
    1   1                             type of contract
    2   1||2||3||4                    number of jobs 
    3   2                             duration contract (no type of contract)
```

thanks

Comment: Your question is very unclear, please clarify your question.

Comment: edited question, maybe more clear. thanks

Comment: I've tried to understand your question so I help, but still failed! Please clarify...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put names of properties in additional table, like

```
Properties
id  name
1   type of contract
2   number of jobs 
3   duration contract (no type of contract)
```

then use 
SpecificProperties

```
foreign key (Employment) foreign key (Properties)
1                        1
1                        2
2                        3
2                        2
```

as junction table reflecting many-many relationship - one or more jobs can have one or more properties, so instead of putting "number of jobs" for every job you just put its id from Properties table.

@comments
But if "number of jobs" is a field and not just a text to display then it shouldn't be in SpecificProperties as row value. Instead it should be somewhere as column name, but not together with contract info. 
Example:
Bob is multimedia designer, working since some date until some other date, on a contract of type x worth somemoney and so on.
Table Contracts (or Employment) with columns (id,user_id,job_id,start_date,end_date,salary) can hold info about that, but because more people can work doing exactly the same to avoid storing redundant data we can use foreign key job_id to Jobs table with columns (id,group_id,job_name,number_available). So we know we can have total 10 designers working in multimedia no matter what contracts they actually got.

Comment: i understand what you suggest, and i think that solves the problem. But i am not totally sure that is the best practice.

Comment: well. yes, is a field. probably solve this problem and creates a bigger one